# get parameter of array in twig loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I dump an array in twig, it gives the following result:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Follow)#364 (3) {
    ["id":"TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Follow":private]=>
    int(1)
    ["follower"]=>
    int(2)
    ["followed"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}

 int(1)

 int(1)
```

How can I access the `follower` parameter inside my loop which is:

```
{% for fol in followers %}

    <pre> {{ dump(fol)  }} </pre>

{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TWIG `attribute` [docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html#attribute). Example:

```
{% for fol in followers %}
    <pre> {{ dump(attribute(fol[0], follower)) }} </pre>
{% endfor %}
```

Please make you sure that you have getters for `follower` in `TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Follow` or `follower` attribute is public.

Or simillarly print value:

```
{% for fol in followers %}
    <pre> {{ fol[0].follower }} </pre>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it is still not working, it gives me Variable "follower" does not exist in TESTBlogBundle:Dashboard:Followers.html.twig at line 10. I am new with twig

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces please provide result of your code. I mean result of `<pre> {{ dump(fol) }} </pre>`.

Comment: The result is in my question, first paragraph

Comment: Thank you very much. I have getter in my Follow entity, and I have follower as public attribute, but the problem is not resolved, even it is very logical what you are saying.

Comment: It still gives me:Impossible to access a key ("0") on a integer variable ("1") in...

Comment: Error occurs because you have little mess in your array `followers`. First element of this array (index `0`) is object, but second and third (indexes `1` and `2`) are integer.

Comment: Thank you very much, based on your comment I found the solution